# C : Compile openSSL project

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to code some c code with openssl...

Let's say I have a file `hello.c` which use openssl.

**hello.c**

```
...
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
...
```

Here is my `makefile` :

**makefile**

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-W -Wall -ansi -pedantic
LDFLAGS=
EXEC=hello

all: $(EXEC)

hello: hello.o main.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

run:
    ./$(EXEC)

.PHONY: clean mrproper

clean:
    rm -rf *.o

mrproper: clean
    rm -rf $(EXEC)`
```

When I run the makefile I get this error :

```
hello.c:4:26: fatal error: openssl/rand.h no such file or directory
 #include <openssl/rand.h>
```

What must I add to the makefile so the compilation works ?
I wasn't able to find any clear example.

Comment: first of all, find the path of the headers of the openssl library and pass it to gcc with the `-I` parameter. Then go on and do the same for the lib files (or switch to a build system such as cmake that handles this awkward stuff for you: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindOpenSSL.html)

Comment: You need to find the path that contains `openssl` path and add `-IThePathYouFound` to `CFLAGS`

Comment: Those should be installed in standard locations and should not need a special `-I` flag. Do you have the openssl header files installed? On most distributions they don't come in the normal package and you need the matching `-dev` or `-devel` package.

Comment: If you are on Linux, you probably need to install `libssl-dev`, Try `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that openssl was indeed in installed, but not the `-devel` packages.

As I am on Opensuse, here are the packages needed, in Yast : 
[image]

Thanks to @Etan Reisner and @Marian